# Migrating from Hibernate to OpenJPA - OneToMany aren't fetched

Tags: hibernate, one-to-many, openjpa

I try to migrate an application from Hibernate to OpenJPA and "suddenly" the @OneToMany relations aren't fetched anymore.

The situation can be summarised as follows: I have two Entities *Member* and *Username*. A member can have multiple username names. Ii is realised in the database by two tables (Member and Username) where the username table contain the member_id as a foreign key column.

This leads to the entities:

```
@Table(name="member")
public class Member implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(unique=true, nullable=false)
private int id;
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="member")
private List<Username> usernames;
    ...
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name="username")
public class Username implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(insertable=false, updatable=false, unique=true, nullable=false)
private int id;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Member
    @ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="member_id", nullable=false)
private Member member;
    ...
```

Both entity classes have public setters and getters for the attributes and a default constructor. (I tried a "plug-and-play" approach and created the classes automatically in Eclipse from an existing DB).

The classes are declared in the *persistence.xml* file

```
<persistence-unit name="...">
    <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
    <class>allwi.data.jpa.Member</class>
    <class>allwi.data.jpa.Username</class>
```

I'm using the JPAContainer of the VAADIN framework to load the data. With hibernate loading the member data and implicitly loading the usernames worked well.
After I switched to OpenJPA, the usernames collection is null. When I call *getUsernames()* on the member object, I still get null returned and no additional fetch is performed. I increased the log-level to TRACE and see that only a simple SQL fetch to the Member table is executed.

I also already tried to add *Fetch=EAGER* and *Cascade=ALL* with no difference.

I must make a silly mistake as it seems that I'm the only one who experience this issue.
As said, I'm using the VAADIN JPAContainer, i.e. basically I have not much influence on the creation  of the entity manager.

What am I missing?

Many thanks

***EDIT 1***

Improved code fragments and added some explanation of the DB design.

***EDIT 2***

I checked, if the behaviour is related to the JPAContainer. Therefore I created the EntityManager manually:

```
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(...);
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();       
    Member m = em.find(Member.class, 14661667);
```

The result is the same: I get the data form the columns of the Member table and I also get the data from the @ManyToOne relationships in Member - like *status* - but not the Collections of the @OneToMany relationships.

***EDIT 3***

I'm using PostgreSQL for the database.

Comment: What column are you using to join Member and Username?  Also, what table contains this column?

Answer (score 0):

It appears your mapping this relationship as a bidirectional relationship judging by the `mappedBy` element on the `@OneToMany` annotation.  You need to add the `@ManyToOne` annotation on the `Username` entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="username")
public class Username implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(insertable=false, updatable=false, unique=true, nullable=false)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id") //this depends on your column name
    private Member member;
```

If this is actually a unidirectional relationship you need to remove the `mappedBy` element and specify a `@JoinColumn` on `Member`

```
@Table(name="member")
public class Member implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(unique=true, nullable=false)
    private int id;

    @Column(name="date_of_birth")
    private Timestamp dateOfBirth;
    ...

    @OneToMany()
    @JoinColumn(name="id") //this depends on the name of the foreign key column
    private List<Username> usernames;
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin ... I cut off the code fragment too early. Yes I have the @ManyToOne/@JoinColumn(name="id") annotation for the Member element in the username class. I'll update the question  to show this

Answer (score 0):

Okay - I have a gut feeling that this issue is related with the enhancement strategy. I used the buildtime enhancement from the Eclipse plugin and run into the issues above (and saw some warning that the classes were enhanced to 1.x instead of "2").

I tried to add the ant builder in eclipse build but even after a successful build, launching the app with the assigned runtime failed with the message that no enhancement was performed.

The runtime enhancement is not recommended, so I skip this but tried EclipseLink instead ... and!? Woohoo - It works again without any change to the implementation.

**Conclusion:** Not everything called "Apache" is great and reliable and for the time being, it highly recommendable to avoid OpenJPA

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should try to use the eager fetch type:

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
```